# Session value not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have saved the session value as follows-

```
        else
        {
            lstCRUserList = objGenericSLImpl.ListAllDataTableGrid(objLoginUserDetails.CompanyDBConnectionString, Convert.ToInt32(gridtype), nDisplayLength, nPage,
                sSortCol, sSortDir, out out_iTotalRecords, sLookUpPrefix, arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5],
                arr[6], arr[7], arr[8], arr[9], arr[10], arr[11], arr[12], arr[13], arr[14], arr[15], arr[16], arr[17], arr[18], arr[19],
                arr[20], arr[21], arr[22], arr[23], arr[24], arr[25], arr[26], arr[27], arr[28], arr[29],
                arr[30], arr[31], arr[32],
                arr[33], arr[34], arr[35], arr[36], arr[37], arr[38], arr[39], arr[40], arr[41], arr[42], arr[43], arr[44], arr[45], arr[46], arr[47],
                arr[48], arr[49]
            );
        }

            Session["Employee"] = lstCRUserList;
```

In the MVC View, jQuery is as follows-

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#19").change(function () {
        debugger;
        var Selected_Entry = $("#19 option:selected").val();

        if (Selected_Entry == 154002) {        
            var No_Of_Emp = '@Session["Employee"]'.ToString();
            var No_Of_Employees = parseInt(No_Of_Emp);
            alert(No_Of_Employees);                                   
        }
        else {

        }
    });
});
```

But the session value is not saving in jQuery, and when debugging jQuery, it shows an error in the browser:

> var No_Of_Emp =
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]'.ToString();

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: `var employees = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Session["Employee"]));`. But your `var No_Of_Employees` code makes no sense - its a collection, not a number.

Comment: Hi Stephen, Thanks for reply, It showing all json data, But actual value still not getting..here lstCRUserList  contains count of records and i want get that count.

Comment: `lstCRUserList` does not contain a count - it contains a collection of objects. If all you want is the count, then use `Session["Employee"] = lstCRUserList.Count();`

Comment: Thanks a lot..Stephen, It's working great...:)